# Gostaria de executar um código que puxasse os dados de uma API, mostrando no excel. Estou usando VBA para isso

Tags: json, api, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

O API que estou usando informa:
{"matricula":"1433620155-2020-4-00256-128-0109252-70","dataLavratura":"2020-02-24","dataInsercao":"2020-02-24T22:46:35","nomeFalecido":"LOURIVAL DE MELO FILHO","dataNascimento":"1954-06-25","sexoFalecido":"MASCULINO","dataObito":"2020-02-23T19:35:00","naturalidade":{"uf":"BA","municipio":"SALVADOR","codigoIBGE":292740},"filiacao":[{"nome":"ARMANDA SANTOS DE MELO","sexo":"FEMININO"},{"nome":"LOURIVAL DE MELO","sexo":"MASCULINO"}],"documentos":[{"tipo":"CPF","numero":"12272043534"}],"possuiRegistrosAnteriores":false}

Meu código até o momento:

Sub SIRC_Obito_API()

'1º passo iniciar o VBA ir no https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON baixar e incluir a biblioteca JSON no modulo
'2º passo habilitar em ferramentas > referências > Microsoft WinHTTP Services e Microsoft Scripting Runtime

'API = https://api-sp.dataprev.gov.br/registro-civil/v1.0.0/obitos?cpf=12272043534&buscaNomeExato=false

Dim requisicao As New WinHttpRequest
Dim resposta As Object
Dim url As String, parametros As String

Do While Range("11").Value = "Then"
fimr = fimr - 1

Sheets("Macro").Select

' Definir a URL e os parâmetros
url = "https://api-sp.dataprev.gov.br/registro-civil/v1.0.0/obitos"
parametros = "?cpf=12272043534&buscaNomeExato=true" & Cells(1, 2).Value

' Enviar a requisição
requisicao.Open "Get", "https://api-sp.dataprev.gov.br/registro-civil/v1.0.0/obitos?cpf=12272043534&buscaNomeExato=true"
requisicao.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer 2862233d-b113-34be-a916-9f7a55faba06"
requisicao.Send

' Tratamento de erros
If requisicao.Status = 200 Then
MsgBox "Erro: " & requisicao.ResponseText
Exit Sub
End If

' Converter o JSON
Set resposta = JsonConverter.ParseJson(requisicao.ResponseText)

' Tratar as informações

```
Dim dados As Collection
Set dados = resposta("documentos")

Cells(11, 1).Value = resposta("tipo")
Cells(12, 1).Value = resposta("numero")
```

'Fim loop

Loop

End Sub

Comment: cara por favor tenta da uma formatada na sua pergunta esta ilegivel.

Answer (score -1):

' API = https://apixxxxxxxxxx=false

Dim requisicao As New WinHttpRequest
Dim resposta As Object
Dim url As String, parametros As String, CPF As String

'Lev    a o cursor para a celula A3
'Range("A3").Select

' Definir a URL
url = "https://api-xxxxxxxx"

'Pega o valor do CPF
CPF = ActiveCell.Value

Do Until CPF = ""

```
' montar parametros
parametros = "?cpf=" & CPF '& "&buscaNomeExato=true"

' montar requisição
requisicao.Open "Get", url & parametros
requisicao.SetRequestHeader "accept", "application/json"
requisicao.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
requisicao.Send

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = requisicao.Status
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 50).Value = requisicao.ResponseText

If requisicao.Status = 200 Then
    ' Converter o JSON
    Set resposta = JsonConverter.ParseJson(requisicao.ResponseText)
    ' Tratar as informações
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = resposta("matricula")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = resposta("dataLavratura")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = resposta("dataInsercao")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = resposta("nomeFalecido")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value = resposta("dataNascimento")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Value = resposta("sexoFalecido")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9).Value = resposta("dataObito")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value = resposta("naturalidade")("uf")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11).Value = resposta("naturalidade")("municipio")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12).Value = resposta("naturalidade")("codigoIBGE")
    
    If resposta.Exists("filiacao") Then
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 13).Value = resposta("filiacao")(1)("nome")
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value = resposta("filiacao")(1)("sexo")
        If resposta("filiacao").Count > 1 Then
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 15).Value = resposta("filiacao")(2)("nome")
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 16).Value = resposta("filiacao")(2)("sexo")
        End If
    End If
    
    If resposta.Exists("cartorio") Then
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 17).Value = resposta("cartorio")("tipo")
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 18).Value = resposta("cartorio")("identificador")
    End If
    
    If resposta.Exists("livro") Then
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 19).Value = resposta("livro")
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 20).Value = resposta("folha")
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 21).Value = resposta("termo")
    End If

    
    Dim tipoDoc
    tipoDoc = Array("CPF", "RG", "NIT", "RIC", "RNE", "TITULO_DE_ELEITOR", "PASSAPORTE", "CNH", "CTPS", "CARTEIRA_DE_MARITIMO", "DOC_ESTRANGEIRO", "CERT_DE_NASCIMENTO", "CERT_DE_RESERVISTA", "NAO_IDENTIFICADO")
    For i = 1 To resposta("documentos").Count
        For d = 0 To 13
            If resposta("documentos")(i)("tipo") = tipoDoc(d) Then
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 22 + d * 2).Value = resposta("documentos")(i)("numero")
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 23 + d * 2).Value = resposta("documentos")(i)("dataEmissao")
            End If
        Next d
    Next i
End If

'Movimenta o cursor para a celula abaixo
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

'Pega o valor do CPF
CPF = ActiveCell.Value
```

Loop

End Sub